# use a formula to define a column to filter in powerquery

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I have an excel source-document with a list of tasks and one column for each weekday containing the time the task runs.
I'd like to create another document that pulls information from several sources and combines data.
My question how can I select only the tasks that need to run today.

I created the code below; where dayname should return the first 3 letters of each day (those are the headers in the table of the sourcedocument). and then I filter on the not null values of that column.

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\document.xlsx"), null, true),
    Table1_Table = Source{[Item="Table1",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
    dayname= Text.Start(Date.DayOfWeekName(),3),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table1_Table,{{"Task", type text}, {"Mon", type any}, {"Tue", type any}, {"Wed", type any}, {"Thu", type any}, {"Fri", type any}, {"Sat", type datetime}, {"Sun", type datetime}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = #!"Table.SelectRows(#""Changed Type"", each ([#dayname] <> null))"
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

edit:
Example source data

| task | mon | tue | wed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 6 am |  | 6 am |
| other | 5 am | 5 am | 5 am |
| xxx | 7 am | 8 am | 9 am |

example result on a  tuesday

| task | today |
| --- | --- |
| other | 5 am |
| xxx | 8 am |

/edit

Comment: Please post some sample data. [See here on how to post minimal reproducible data.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Post sample data and sample desired outcome, otherwise we can't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load your data into Power Query.

[image]

Then unpivot it.

[image]

The days column heading will be pivoted into an **Attribute** column.

The **Attribute** column values can then be filtered by the current date reformatted as a three letter day name.

Remove the **Attribute** column and rename the **Value** column.

[image]

The M code:

```
 let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"task ", type text}, {"mon ", type time}, {"tue", type time}, {"wed", type time}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"task "}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", each ([Attribute] = 
    Text.Start(
        Text.Lower(
            Date.DayOfWeekName(
                DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow())
            ,"en-us")
        )
    ,3))),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Value", "Today"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```